# My Tab in the ms.windows explorer

Tags: delphi

There is such a small free program - HashTab (http://www.implbits.com/HashTab/HashTabWindows.aspx). Once installed, it adds a tab to the standard windows file properties and can count checksums of files.

[image: hashtab]

How this can be done (to set a my tab in the windows explorer file properties (on win exp. on any file - right mouse click menu -> properties))? **DelphiXe4.**

p.s. Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: [`This article`](http://www.codeproject.com/shell/ShellExtGuide5.asp) describes how to do what you want in C++. But it's quite outdated, so hard to say if it still applies to recent versions of Windows.

Comment: @Gu understand and translate basic C++ code to Delphi is a necessary skill for any Delphi developer.

Comment: lurk around http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/shell-extension-for-windows-32-bit-and-64-bit-with-delphi-xe2/

Comment: you would need to make both win32 and win64 explorer plugins

Comment: 2 RRUZ - do not agree. I c++ does not like.

Comment: If you want to respond to someone specifically and have them notified so they actually spot your response which they might otherwise miss: use `2<username>`, in this case @RRUZ instead of 2 RRUZ. And StackOverflow even has autocomlete on these @ mentions (as they are called). I didn't have to use an @ mention to get you notified, because you are the post owner and are always notified automatically.

Comment: Whether you *like* C++ doesn't matter. If you're going to program for Windows, you need to know how to read C and C++ because those are the languages that the platform manufacture writes its APIs and documentation in, whether *you* like it or not.

Comment: @Gu. If you want to avoid C++ then you should abandon this task right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [`Property Sheet Handlers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You can try the [MSDN  documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which includes a c++ sample.

Comment: The direction of where to dig there, that's enough. Thank you.

Comment: good for you, now you can try to write the shell extension (using the IShellPropSheetExt) and if you have any specific doubt you can ask a new question.